# Download OpenCV for Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I have literally spent numerous hours trying to install OpenCV on Pycharm but have not succeeded. I have gone through numerous SO answers and blog posts but still without any luck. I followed [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) which seemed to work(when I tried the samples) but Pycharm is still not recognizing any of opencv, cv, cv2 as modules and keeps displaying ImportError. How can I install opencv so that it works for Pycharm?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and python 3.4 for Pycharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont install opencv in Pycharm but on your OS and at your python environment.

For some reason i cant comment but,

You need to tell us :

**A) Your OS**

**B) PYTHON environment 2.x 3.x , anaconda? canopy? winpython?**

*So we can properly reply.*

But yes, you must **install opencv to your python environment**

---

For Ubuntu, this is what you should do:

**git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git**

**cd ~/opencv**

**mkdir release**

**cd release**

**cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..**

**make**

**sudo make install**

If you are using virtualenv, you have to activate it first.
If not, just follow above.

**Reference**

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Edit:
Be sure to have Git installed.

It helps a lot with installing certain python packages.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still trying. My internet is dead slow. I'll let you know when I'm done for sure.

Comment: I forgot to tell you, when doing *make* you can add -j 2 or -j *any number of cores* , it makes it faster.

Comment: This downloads opencv3. Any way to download opencv2 in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python 3.7.6
Then in Pycharm > Settings > Project # > Project interpreter
Verify that you are using Python 3.7
then Add Package (+)
search for opencv-python and install it

I get the info from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQeoO7MI0Bs&t=29s

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).